# A timer for suspend similar to the shutdown utility

Tags: bash, arch-linux, systemd

Anyway to set a timer to suspend the system say in 120 minutes similar to doing:

```
$ shutdown 120
```

But for suspension. I want to encode some stuff in handbrake and I want my pc to automatically go to sleep after so much time.

Comment: `sleep 120m && systemctl suspend` ? Unless you want to use `systemd-inhibit` (as [suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104162))...

Comment: If you additionally want to lock your PC first, ISTR having to use e.g. `sudo sh -c 'sleep 120m && systemctl suspend'`.  The screen lock seems to revoke your console permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) to schedule any action.

Firstly, you have to install `at`:

```
sudo pacman -S at
# or
sudo apt install at
```

Then, start service `at`:

```
systemctl start atd
```

And now you can do something like that:

```
echo 'pmi action suspend' | at 4pm
```

Or like that:

```
echo pm-suspend | sudo at now + 10 min
```